# Encoding Eclipse debugger vs JVM

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, character-encoding

I tried to save a path I get from `file.getAbsolutePath()` in a File. The problem is that one file has a `č` in the name. A `println()` shows the `č` as `?` but I can use the String to create a new file same name and the `č` appears. So I guess in encoding used by the JVM is not the right. I have tried a couple of encodings but none of them gets a `č` at this point. I have running the debug-mode of Eclipse and it shows the `č` correctly.

**So my question is:** Which is the default encoding of the default debugger variables view? Or is there a way to save the string without losing the `č`?

```
a = file.getAbsolutePath();
a.compare(new String(file.getAbsolutePath().getBytes()));
```

This gives `0` with other pathes not with a path `č`.
`äüö` are not a problem.

Comment: For example, `a.compare(new String(file.getAbsolutePath().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));` will give `0` for all pathes. On `println()` and `getBytes()` characters may be lost if a non-UTF encoding is used. In Java, a string instance itself has no encoding, since it is made up of Unicode characters.

Comment: `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`  works for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use a UTF charset** like [**`StandardCharsets.UTF_8`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8) on encoding and the same on decoding to avoid losing characters.

For example,

```
a = file.getAbsolutePath();
a.compare(new String(file.getAbsolutePath().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

will give `0` for all paths (with and without `č`). On `getBytes()` and `println()` characters may be lost if a non-UTF encoding is used. In Java, a string instance itself has no encoding, since it is made up of Unicode characters.